# Excel increment formula every 92 rows

Tags: excel, vba, formula, increment

I have trying to connect values from 1 inventory sheet to another.

Each item has 92 options, 14k gold, 18k gold, ring size etc. 92 total

The values for each row for the item are as follows:
    =$M$4
    =$N$4
    =$O$4
..etc

This connects column values in another sheet to the second one.

Every 92 rows I want the last number '$4' to increase by 4: $4..$8..$12 without changing the letter.

How can I do this?

I have no experience in programming, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you have no programming experience, I recommend going through a learning program.

Comment: I'm not clear on the requirement. Which is the first cell you want populated? I assume that should get you `=M4` - what should be in the next cell down, N4?

Comment: $M$4 from another excel file allrings.xlsx the sequence of the letter is below for every set M M M M N O O P P Q Q R R M M M M N O O P P Q Q R R M M M M N O O P P Q Q R R S S S S T U U V V W W X X S S S S T U U V V W W X X S S S S T U U V V W W X X Y Y Y Y Z AA AA AB AB AC AC AD AD

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a formula, no VBA needed.

If in column A you want to get the value from M4 for the first 92 rows, then the value of M8 for the next 92 rows, then the value of M12 for the next 92, and so on down Column A. Then in A1 enter the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("M"&4+((FLOOR(ROW(),92)/92)*4))
```

This is kind of ugly, so I'll attempt to break it down, from the inside of the formula to the outside.

1. Row() - This will return the row for the cell that contains this formula. A1 will return "1"
2. Floor(Row(), 92) - This will return the lowest multiple of 92 for each row. A1 will return 0, A92 will return 92, A105 will also return 92 as it's the lowest multiple of 92 for 105
3. (FLOOR(ROW(),92)/92) - This just divide the results of floor by 92 so we get 1 for A1-A91, 2 for A92-A183, etc..
4. ((FLOOR(ROW(),92)/92)*4) - Now multiple that by 4 because you are interested in incrementing by four: Cell `M4`, `M8`, etc..
5. 4+((FLOOR(ROW(),92)/92)*4) - Add four to the result, since your first cell is M4
6. =INDIRECT("M"&4+((FLOOR(ROW(),92)/92)*4)) - Indirect takes a text value like "M4" and makes it a cell reference. Excel then goes and gets the value of the cell reference. For A1 after we do all of our math on Row() we get `"M" & 4` or `M4`. `=Indirect("M4")` then gets the value from M4.

So, stick that formula in A1 and copy it down as far you as you want and it will increment every 92 rows to go from M4, M8, M12, M16, ...

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention I want it for 91 rows in a column where the first cell is empty. And the $M$4 value is from a separate worksheet "all-rings.xlsx", I want it to grab values from this separate worksheet.

Comment: In that case, change the 92 to a 91. Since you are starting in the second row, then change `ROW()` to `ROW()-1`. Since it's in a different workbook then you'll have to change the `"M"` to reference the workbook, the worksheet, and then the cell, so `"[all-rings.xlsx]Sheet1!M"` should work.

Comment: Also, its not just M column, the following is the sequence of columns:    M
M
M
M
N
O
O
P
P
Q
Q
R
R
M
M
M
M
N
O
O
P
P
Q
Q
R
R
M
M
M
M
N
O
O
P
P
Q
Q
R
R
S
S
S
S
T
U
U
V
V
W
W
X
X
S
S
S
S
T
U
U
V
V
W
W
X
X
S
S
S
S
T
U
U
V
V
W
W
X
X
Y
Y
Y
Y
Z
AA
AA
AB
AB
AC
AC
AD
AD - for the 91 rows - I am sorry for not being more clear upfront

Comment: Can you still help? Let me know if you need any further information